# nginx: nginx reverse proxy works in server but not working on localhost

Tags: javascript, nginx, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I have a backend service that uses prisma/graphql. and backend is running on port 4001.
This is the proxy-pass of my Nginx config file `proxy_pass:http://$host:4001`

when I run it from the server it works on both `http://server:4001` and `http://server`
But, when I run it from localhost, I am getting the following error:

`no resolver defined to resolve localhost, client: 172.30.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"`

what causes this error and how to fix it?

docker-compose:

```
backend:
    image: base
    command: >
      sh -c "npm run deploy && npm run start"
    env_file: ${ENV_FILE}
    ports:
      - '4001:4001'
    depends_on:
      - prisma
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./deploy/certs:/deploy/certs

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./deploy/certs:/deploy/certs
      - ./deploy/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - 80:80/tcp
      - 443:443/tcp
    depends_on:
      - backend
    restart: always
    env_file: ${ENV_FILE}
```

nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://$host:4001;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would need to connect to your `backend` service specified in `docker-compose.yml` in the `nginx.conf` file.

For e.g.

```
upstream localhost {
  server backend:4001;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;
}
```

Could you try this one?

Comment: I have tried this. and got same error.
`nginx_1      | 2020/05/12 09:19:43 [error] 6#6: *2 no resolver defined to resolve localhost, client: 172.30.0.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"`